# Angular Multiplying a Row of a Table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a table and the user can add a new empty row, to the table. I've put a multiply  button next to every row. I want the user to be able to click this button and when a dialog opens and he says multiply, I want a copy of that row with the same information to be added to the table. I don't have a clue on how to perform this task. Here is my code, how can I manage this?

HTML of the copy-dialog component:

```
<button mat-stroked-button class="amber-fg mr-12" (click)="multiply()">Multiply</button>
```

TS:

```
  multiply(){

  }
```

TS of the table component:

```
addNewWorkItem() { //adds a new, empty row
    let item: IWorkItem = {};
    item.WorkItemStateType = this.workItemStates[0];
    item.Product = {};

    let tempData = this.dataSource.data.splice(0);
    tempData.unshift(item);

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tempData);
    this.EditIndex = 0;
    this.products = [];
}

openCopyDialog(prm) {
    const dialogRef = this._dialog.open(CopyDialogComponent, {
        width: "700px",
        data: prm,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
        //console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I suppose that your table displays data from some array. If you want to add new row then you simply need to push new item into that array.

Comment: I can add a new row, but it's an empty, new row. I want a copy of a selected row and add that to the table.

Comment: The HTML part would be valuable since if you are rendering with a mat table you need to provide the dataset which you are rendering. Then you can send the object used and take the information out of it. But this requires the HTML you're using